# Dashboard using output results from Jenkins API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dashboard, jenkins-scriptler

I am new to Jenkins API. I just had assignement in company where PL asked me to create a new job in Jenkins where I will run all the testing,build related things on my code and it should create dashboard where all figures and graph should be shown. He said that its feasible. Can anyone please guide me to do so.

Comment: Please be more clear about what kind of graphs and figures you are talking about.

Comment: It should show compilation error number,Test cases run result, JUnit test cases run result. So how many files, number of files having error, total test cases run/failed/successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Sectioned-Vew-Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sectioned+View+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Job on Jenkins and add /api after the Url. You could see the API Information related to the Job you have just created. The API will contain the Get End points for Retrieving the data. Its available in JSON as well as XMl which you can parse and use as the source of Info for your dashboard. You can also trigger a new Build by using the Post API.